# how can I transfer a Maven project to a normal project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

Here a maven project build in IDEA, now i want to use eclipse develop it, but don't want to use maven ,so that others can use ADT to Integration the project

the project in IDEA as folows , there are many Dependencies in pom.xml，so agonizing

how should I do ? thanks in advance

Comment: i just signed up stackoverflow, and my reoutation is below 10,so i can't post my projecst struture as a picture in my question, sorrry

Comment: What is your objection to Maven? Managing 3rd party dependencies is not a trivial issue.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question,I know maven is a good tool for project development,all i want to know is how to translate maven project to a normal project,can you give me same advice?

Comment: m2eclipse is good at opening a maven project in eclipse so you don't have to break your dependency tools to work with.